# IsWow64Process PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION check on process handle

Tags: c++, winapi, wow64

Simple question, but is there a win32 API call to retrieve if a process handle has the `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` access flag in order to successfully call `IsWow64Process`? [AccessCheck Function - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems like it'd work but I'm not sure if that's checking the same sort of flags.

Comment: Why not just call `IsWow64Process()` unconditionally and handle any error it might return? That would be far easier than trying to dig into the security system's internals.

Comment: Yes I figured I could do that, but I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it otherwise :]

Comment: It might be obvious, but the MSDN page doesn't tell: `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (0x5) when trying to use `IsWow64Process()` on a handle that doesn't have the required access flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`NtQueryObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383.aspx) function.  Set its `ObjectInformationClass` parameter to `ObjectBasicInformation` to request the handle's `PUBLIC_OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION` struct, which has a `GrantedAccess` member of type [`ACCESS_MASK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374892.aspx), which might contain `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`.